# Add ability to show "votes" question view by date range

Tags: feature-request, voting, views, tabs

It would be great if i could see only the highest voted questions within a date range, sort of like the "week" or "month" tabs on the main page. Can this be added?

Comment: Anyone? anyone at all?

Comment: Oh, bounty time! Maybe Jarrod needs some rep...

Comment: Hmm what happens if there's no answers on a bounty question? i guess we will find out...